# AWS DynamoDB and Nodejs integration - how to filter between two dates?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a small nodejs script connected to my DynamoDB and one of my primary sort keys is datetime, which is represented in UTC.

I would like to filter the results by a certain date and time and am having issues with my Filter Expression.

```
var params = {
  TableName: "realtimeusers",
  ProjectionExpression: "brand, datetime, activeusers",
  KeyConditionExpression: "brand = :brand",
  FilterExpression: "datetime > :today",
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ":brand": "BRAND A",
    ":today": 1464705900
  },
};
```

I get the error message:

```
 "message": "Invalid FilterExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: datetime",
```

I think I am missing something in my filter expression that I don't fully grasp.

Can some one please help?

Comment: Do you have an attribute DATETIME in your dynamo record? It's a reserved keyword. Try using Expression attribute names. Here is the link to the aws documentation. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html

Comment: @Shibashis Yes I do, does that mean I shouldn't have it and should delete my database and restart?

Comment: Dont delete anything. Use Expression attribute names http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ExpressionPlaceholders.html#ExpressionAttributeNames

Comment: Ok, will have a look thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"datetime" is a reserved dynamo keyword. The reserved keywords are not allowed in dynamo query expressions.

The way around this is to use Expression attribute names when querying for such properties.

Reference:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ReservedWords.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ExpressionPlaceholders.html#ExpressionAttributeNames